# Being Investigated at work. What should I do?

Tags: work-environment

I am a manager for a retail company (company known brand) and I was just told I’m being investigated because $200 went missing back in October 2021. Mind you, we’re in February 2022.

I had no idea this happened and I told them I would never do such a thing, and told them everything I knew. But then they said I gave out too many discounts to an associate and I violated the code of conduct and lost the company a value of $150.

I told them I don’t remember this happening and that I don’t know was basically my answer for everything. I really didn’t remember because this happened months ago! And I said if they would have asked sooner I would have had a better answer. But, I also didn’t want to say much because I didn’t want to self-incriminate.

They as well asked if I would pay the company for the profit they lost and I said no.

They told me that I would be under investigation and that not to be surprised if it ended badly.

So what do I do?

I already had another job lined up and was already planning to put in my 2 weeks notice.

Should I even do that now or just quit?

I don’t want to look “guilty” or “bad” because I’m not but I also don’t want “terminated” on my record either.

I really don’t care to burn my bridges with this company because I’ve written complaints about bullying, harassment, and even racism at work and nothing has been done.

So any advice or options would help!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134309/discussion-on-question-by-alexis-being-investigated-at-work-what-should-i-do).

Comment: Your country and state/province/region may be relevant to this question. You should edit your post and add some location tags

Comment: The other associate that I gave the discounts too is being investigated as well. They did try to pin us against each other by saying “she said this” “she said you stole $200” and more stuff like that to get us to confess to something we didn’t do. They as well made us sign some paperwork about what happened and how we’re going to be under investigation (I wish I didn’t sign anything after reading all the comments and answers)

Comment: My co worker said she would pay back the money and she takes full responsibility for it (was not aware she said that) I asked her why she say that and she’s like it probably was her fault and she just didn’t remember. They told her “you must really like each other to be taking the blame” saying how they are going to look at our facebooks and Instagram to make sure we’re not friends and all this other bs

Comment: So by her saying that I’m not really sure how this will go, but I do know she did just quit and I’m still debating on what to do. We’ve both have put up with a lot from this company just to turn on us. I’m looking to just quit because like I said I don’t care to burn my bridges with them. I don’t want to work for someone who’s a bully and racist

Answer (score 158):

They're not looking to steal your final paycheck. They're looking to discredit you. You've complained about harassment and racism, they want a paper trail to claim you have a grudge in case you sue. They would have loved for you to have paid, because that would look like an admission of guilt.  If you already have a new job just get out and consider talking to a lawyer to see if you have a case.

Comment: I have thought about looking for a lawyer but I didn’t do anything wrong, and they didn’t even address these “problems” until we filed reports on my store mangers for all of the harassment, bullying and racism. She isn’t under investigation it’s just me and the co worker I gave the discounts too. But that co worker has had many! Problems with our store manger so I’m just thinking they want us out since we’ve been trying to put a end to all the bs at work

Comment: Unfortunately, it is very common for corporations to "investigate" people who file reports for racism or other such cultural issues. Whistle blowers get investigated, demoted, and a paper trail is built to expel them from the organization. That is why laws had to be passed in the US to try to protect them, but the laws don't work very well. Move on and do that quickly.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The lawyer comment wasn't about the investigation (none needed for that), but more about  whether the level of racism and discrimination he saw rises to the level of actionable.  We don't have enough info here to tell.

Comment: I don't think the lawyer comment was about defending against their allegation; I think it's about going on the offensive against them for the way you were treated prior

Comment: @Alexis--From the way you describe the events that took place--leveling false accusations, demanding money, and then threatening you with an ominous "things may not end well" when you refused to confess to something you didn't do--this almost certainly meets the criteria for workplace harassment and it doesn't even cover whatever other abuse you experienced while working at this place.. You can and should find a lawyer to find out if it would be feasible to sue them and get compensated for the wrongs you've been dealt. Companies shouldn't be allowed to get away with this nonsense.

Comment: “I didn’t do anything wrong” DOES NOT EQUAL “I don’t need a lawyer”, the two statements aren’t even in the same country, let alone the same zip code.

Comment: "I have thought about looking for a lawyer but I didn’t do anything wrong" -- most often than not, you don't need a lawyer when guilty.

Comment: Note that **retaliation** against a person who complains is directly an offense, and oftentimes is easier to prove that the original complaint. That the complaint was frivolous *is no defence*. TL;DR you have much *more* of a case *now*.

Answer (score 118):

I have worked retail in the past, and I was in the management track.

Cash policies could be much more strict, and when I asked about them, a regional manager quietly admitted to me that they were deliberately vague so that they could get rid of people.  The running joke is that people leave retail 2 ways.  They quit, or they are accused of stealing.

The cash policies are so lax by design because any money missing (and there is always money missing) can be blamed on anyone.  The standard strategy is to accuse you of stealing, then have you sign something where you agree to having stolen, and they agree not to prosecute.  So, they can claim "Fired for cause" and not pay unemployment.

Retail is a dirty, dirty business.

**SIGN NOTHING** and refuse to discuss any legalities without a lawyer present.

If they push the issue, sit down with a lawyer because some companies can be vindictive.  If you go the lawyer route, have the lawyer negotiate the best terms for you to leave on, including no negative marks in your file and/or in any shared databases and for them to not flag you as a "do not rehire".

Comment: In principle wouldn't the state be able to prosecute your for stealing, even if the company has agreed not to prosecute? The state prosecutor didn't sign the agreement.

Comment: @bdsl In practice, the state prosecutor would never hear about the case, certainly not for such a petty amount.

Comment: @bdsl only if there were actual evidence that would stand up in a criminal case. Which is a far higher standard than a civil suit where vague accusations can often lead to big settlements.

Answer (score 45):

In real investigations, you don't confront the person being investigated and start demanding confessions. If you are confronted with such an accusation, the proper action is to first make a simple, unemotional and direct denial to the asshat who confronts you. Then you should immediately draft and send a letter to your superior or to your superior's superior if it was your superior who confronted you, and cc human resources. The letter should read, "Today [date] I was confronted by [person's name] at [time] in [place], and this person accused me of stealing. This accusation is completely false, baseless, defamatory and insulting to my honor. I hope you will take immediate and decisive action to see to it that in the future, neither I and nor other employees at [company name] are accused of theft or other crimes without conclusive physical evidence proving both that a crime has occurred and they have done it. Sincerely, etc"

They either have real evidence or they don't and it sounds like they don't.

The status of their "investigation" should have absolutely nothing to do with your career movements. You should simply continue on whatever path you were already on.

If the company tries to dock your pay, immediately file a complaint with your state. In the United States failure to pay an employee is not tolerated and there are forms you can fill out that will ensure you are paid immediately by your employer. In most states the legal penalties for failing to pay an employee are sudden and SEVERE. A judge in the United States can and will literally throw your bosses in jail if they don't pay you and I am not kidding.

Comment: +1 excellent advice to not be fearful of confrontation and to be direct in denying accusation. You did nothing wrong, so what harm can result from being direct?

Comment: This is a great answer for the specific things to say and how to handle

Comment: I second the "do not be fearful of confrontation". I have been harassed by very bad (ethically) people in past several years and have found that de-escalation or calming or agreeing to "facts not in evidence" actually feeds their fires due to them gaining confidence that they can control you. It is a very different way of treating people that I have learnt the hard way should be addressed early and clearly.

Comment: I think your last paragraph is too optimistic. Wage theft is very common in the U.S., and although there have been some criminal prosecutions, they do not begin to approach the scale of the problem. (See https://www.epi.org/publication/wage-theft-2021/ and https://www.epi.org/publication/fighting-workplace-abuses-criminal-prosecutions-of-wage-theft-and-other-employer-crimes-against-workers/ for some statistics.)

Comment: @ruakh LOL those documents are talking about petty things like whether employers pay for smoke breaks and things like that. In the US if an employer does not pay an employee their wage the worker can fill out a form (in Mass it is called a pink sheet) and the employer will be summoned to court in less than 2 weeks, often faster and the judge will make sure the employee is paid immediately. As I said in my post, judges are empowered to do pretty much anything to accomplish this. Don't believe? Trying running a business and not paying somebody and watch what happens to you.

Comment: @ruakh Also, your idea that there are "prosecutions" is ridiculous. There are no prosecutions. If you don't pay your employees, there is no trial or prosecution. The judge just THROWS YOU IN JAIL for real. I am not kidding. Then he will seize your bank accounts, your car, and anything else his deputies can find that belongs to you. Wage non-payment is no joke in the United States. Prosecutions, LOL. The judge can even arrest and jail without trial your family members or even just your friends if he thinks you have given money to them. Wife, girlfriend, anybody that has the money.

Comment: I thought you could only go to jail or even have a court order if the amount that was stolen was over $400. Not $200 and $150 in discounts. At least for the state of Colorado. The way you’re saying it is like they stole thousands of dollars

Comment: @Alexis Failing to pay wages is not "stealing". A wage is a kind of debt. States have laws that make it crime not to pay wages and judges are given special powers to enforce those laws. In Massachusetts for example read this: https://www.mass.gov/service-details/enforcement-authority  the part about "civil citation" is the relevant part. These "citations" are heard by administrative judges who can rule without a prosecutor and issue court orders to seize property, padlock businesses or even throw business owners in jail with no trial (for "contempt of court").

Answer (score 27):

I worked in retail management for years, and *did* have to fire someone for stealing.  I also was aware of another manager who was fired for the kind of stealing you're suggesting they accused you of.

I can tell you that, 100% for certain, if they had any reason to believe you were doing any of the things you mention in your post, they would be handling things *very* differently, especially if this is a major retail chain.

The person we fired for stealing, the moment we had reason to believe they were stealing, was *immediately* removed from the cash wrap, and sent to an in-office location that was monitored; we then let them know that they were caught, *on tape*, stealing, and told them what would happen next - they would go home, they would not come back into the store, and when everything was wrapped up in terms of official documentation they would come back to receive their final check (assuming it was sooner than the check would otherwise are given) and would sign a paper indicating that they understood what was happening.  No "confession" necessary, and *absolutely* no chance they'd spend a moment on the clock or behind a cash register.

If you were believed to be giving improper discounts, you would find out for the first time when they were ready to write you up - whether to directly fire you, or more likely a PIP (this depends on the circumstances and the store, but I find this a more likely scenario where you are written up but not fired for a first offense).  Again, you wouldn't find out orally; you'd find out in a sit down in the office with paperwork.

If you want to address the issue while you're still working there (and honestly I mostly likely wouldn't if you're leaving soon), I suggest you would be best served to talk to your Regional Director or whatever the first level of management is that is not physically present at your store at least once a week.  That person more than likely would not have a grudge against you; they more than likely don't know you (unless you're a higher level of manger that the person accusing you is this level, then you'd need to go a few levels higher).  Not one level above whomever is accusing you, but two or more.  Probably not home office level, though, unless you're only two levels below that.  I don't necessarily think this is likely to be productive, with you already giving your notice soon, but if it helps you feel better about the situation it's what I'd suggest.

Hand in your notice tomorrow, work out your notice period and then leave with your head held high; these kinds of accusations are garbage and clearly meant to intimidate you.

Comment: They definitely have favorites at my job and you can just tell. It’s hard to talk to anyone higher up when everyone is friends, so I’ll definitely have to find someone even higher. But I’m leaving so I don’t really care anymore. This job has cause me so much stress and really has affected my mental health and all the drama not being handled is ridiculous. They showed they only care about money here and nothing else.

Answer (score 8):

I'd surmise that all this is happening in retaliation for you raising the issues about bullying and racism, as others have mentioned.  Do yourself a favor.  If you've lined up a better opportunity, zip your lip on all these issues, and bounce.  This thing about having a perfect record -- you're not in high school!  What will count at your next job, MAYBE, is having good references during the interview process, and it's nothing new that people can't always use their former bosses as a reference.

If the company is going to refer these accusations to law enforcement, you can't stop them.  But they'll have to have enough to sway someone to open a case.  They may be asked the same questions you're asking, i.e. why the company has waited so long to make it an issue.  IF it goes forward, you'll have your chance to share your account with someone who's not biased.  But we're going to hope for the best here, because this is sounding like a bunch of bluffing, and not much more (to me).

Give your notice, and focus on your new job.  Be prepared to raise some hell if your company tries to dock your pay or withhold your last paycheck, but research the appropriate laws in your state instead of arguing blindly as this is the best way to get the intended result.  You got this!

Comment: It’s funny you say it’s not high school when there is so much drama there like it’s high school lol. I already have my new job lined up and a start date so I’m not worried about the interview anymore and I have references from other job, even this job by people who don’t work there no more. I doubt they can make a case with little to no evidence. The only evidence they have is the amount of money is missing and who did the transaction for the discount. Not who stole the $200 though. And I’ve heard in the state of Colorado it needs to be $400+ in order to get a case to court other than that

Comment: It’s a written warning or could be fired if they wanted too. Legally as well they can’t hold or Dock my pay. They on the other hand can’t give me my pto if I do quit sadly

Answer (score 5):

**Quit immediately.  Don't pay anything.  Don't sign anything.**

This is one of the few cases where serving your 2 weeks notice is likely not in your best interest.  Good retail shops have discounts and "house tabs" programmed into their POS system, and the system will cut you off if you're being too generous.

**If you had actually stolen anything they'd have fired you on the spot**. They are using the investigation tactic to try and prevent you from getting unemployment.

If you quit immediately, they will have no reason to continue the trumped-up investigation.  They got what they wanted, you leaving.  Every day you stay you're giving them a chance to fire you for fat-fingering a receipt or clocking out 2 minutes early.

By quitting immediately you're protecting yourself from your unscrupulous employer.  They are already acting in bad faith, get out as quickly as possible.

And to reiterate again.  **Quit immediately, Don't pay.  Don't sign anything**. They don't need you to sign anything to not pay you.  Assume they will lie and try and trick you.

**EDIT**

You're going to be treated badly for the 2 weeks as well.  Just one more ancillary reason to quit immediately.

There is zero upside to staying.  If you stay, they'll probably find a tiny mistake and fire you over it.  **If someone calls to check employment they'll say you were "fired for cause".**

**If you quit immediately they'll likely only verify dates of employment.**

You can't use this job as a reference, and your boss has already burned all the bridges.  Get out now.

Comment: That’s what I’ve heard, some people have told them they put in their two weeks and get treated badly the rest of the time there and I’ve seen it happen to my other co workers at this job.

Comment: "If you did nothing wrong then you have nothing to fear, cooperate fully." Tell that to all the people who have been wrongfully imprisoned or executed.

Comment: @WaterMolecule I think you posted on the [wrong answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/182928/6091)

Answer (score 2):

> ...I’m being investigated because $200 went missing back in October 2021. Mind you, we’re in February 2022.

This is not uncommon, accounting and the subsequent investigation takes time.  If you did nothing wrong then you have nothing to fear, cooperate fully.  If you did, offer to pay back the missing funds, to make this "go away".

> ...they said I gave out too many discounts to an associate and I violated the code of conduct and lost the company a value of $150.

This sounds like a bunch of nonsense.  Did you violate company policy?  It does not sound like it as "too many" discounts is vague.  If the policy was 3 discounts per month, and you gave out 5 then I can understand their issue.  Claiming that it falls under the general umbrella of "code of conduct" is a bunch of BS.

> didn’t want to say much because I didn’t want to self-incriminate.

You only have something to fear if you did something that violated their definitive policy.  If you gave out discounts, and were authorized to do so, then all is good.

> They as well asked if I would pay the company for the profit they lost and I said no.

Rather than saying "no", I would say first let me see what my lawyer says.  If necessary seek out the services of an employment lawyer, but that will most likely make them go away.  An employment lawyer make take your case on contingency and make this a ruling in your favor.

Now if you did actually violate policy, then you should probably pay the money back.

> They told me that I would be under investigation and that not to be surprised if it ended badly.

What is badly?  You need to find another job?  Okay that happens every day.  This is just a bluff.

> I already had another job lined up and was already planning to put in my 2 weeks notice.

Then do so, this investigation has nothing to do with your decision to move on.

> Should I even do that now or just quit?
>
> I don’t want to look “guilty” or “bad” because I’m not but I also don’t want “terminated” on my record either.

If it was me, I would not quit.  I would put in my 2 weeks notice when I was ready, and move on.  Be friendly and happy, show up on time.  Just to be on the safe side, I would avoid giving out any discounts.

In the end, it does not matter what these idiots think of you.  They already think you are guilty and will probably all be replaced within 3 to 5 years.  Having a "terminated" on your record means nothing.

While stressful, all this is a bunch of BS.

Comment: They would not tell me what is “too” much in discounts just that they lost that much profit $150 in total. I said I wouldn’t pay it back because I didn’t remember giving them out because it was months ago. The co worker who’s also being investigated with me said she would pay it back (I don’t know why) but they told her basically she’s taking the “whole” blame but she has just quit now. So I’m not sure exactly what to do. I know they were trying to pin us against each other and say “she said this about you” “she said you stole the $200” and stuff like that to make us confess to things

Comment: I know my job is very unprofessional and the loss prevention manager that I was talking to was also rude af. He was just accusing us and bring up how we reported and that because we were reporting so much that’s the only reason he found this out and then accused us of stealing because we have a “ vendetta“ on the company since we’ve been complaining and reporting. I think that’s ridiculous!